# LINQ to Objects - Generic conversion of ICollection's property to CSV

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I've been writing this out a few different places in my code and I want to create a single, generic function, but I can't quite figure out how.

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
public static string FormatCompaniesAsCSV(ICollection<Company> companies)
{
    string csv = "";
    foreach(Company c in companies)
    {
        csv += c.CompanyName + ",";
    }

    return csv.Substring(0, csv.LastIndexOf(","));
}
```

The problem is that I have to write essentially the same code if I want to display all company SKUs or all of the factories where this is manufactured. The only thing that changes is the object type and the property I am accessing. What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
public static string FormatCSV<T>(ICollection<T> elements, string propertyName)
{
    string csv = "";
    foreach(T element in elements)
    {
        //I know this next line doesn't work
        //this is just a high level conceptualization of what I want to do
        csv += element.getPropertyValue(propertyName) + ","; 
    }

    return csv.Substring(0, csv.LastIndexOf(","));
}
```

I need some way to access the properties of the element in the foreach loop, but I don't really know where to start. I've briefly looked at the System.Linq.Expressions library, but I didn't find quite what I was looking for there.

Am I on the right track? If not, is there a better way to accomplish what I would like to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you pass in a delegate:

```
public static string FormatAsCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements,
                                    Func<T, string> converter) 
{ 
    string csv = ""; 
    foreach(T element in elements) 
    { 
        csv += converter(element) + ","; 
    } 

    return csv.Substring(0, csv.LastIndexOf(",")); 
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
FormatAsCsv(companies, x => x.CompanyName);
FormatAsCsv(factories, x => x.ZipCode + " " + x.City);
```

You could even create an extension method out of it by adding `this` before the type of the first parameter:

```
public static string FormatAsCSV<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements,
                                    Func<T, string> converter)
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
companies.FormatAsCsv(x => x.CompanyName);
factories.FormatAsCsv(x => x.ZipCode + " " + x.City);
```

BTW: I changed the type from `ICollection<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` as you are only using features of `IEnumerable<T>`.

And you can improve the generation of the CSV string:

```
public static string FormatAsCSV<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements,
                                        Func<T, string> converter) 
{
    return elements.Select(x => converter(x)).Aggregate((x, y) => x + "," + y);
}
```

Comment: This is more elegant than using reflection to get the property value from a string. I would also suggest to use String.Join instead of manually concatenating commas, this would also allow to eliminate the Substring call. Something like             return String.Join(",", from e in elements select converter(e));

Comment: @AlvaroRodriguez: Thanks for the suggestion. I like using `Aggregate` more and changed the code accordingly.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I had tried playing around with passing in a delegate, but couldn't get it to work out. I agree, I really love the type-safe nature of LINQ, so I'm much happier using a delegate rather than reflection. Also, thanks Alvaro for the Join suggestion. That is a much more elegant solution than the substring I used at the end - it's especially handy because I don't have to worry about whether the return value has a delimeter in it or not.

Answer (score 0):

The concat with commas can be done in 1 line:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Hi", "Old" };
string line = String.Join(",", list.ToArray());
```

You could also write an extension method (like so)

```
public static string SuperJoin(string joinCharacter, IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    return String.Join(",", strings.ToArray());
}
```

Then use Linq to select out just the field from your object that you want to combine. No delegates needed

Comment: yup. should've been (this string joinCharacter

Comment: Nope. That doesn't make any sense.